# setting value of textbox in forms

Tags: php, javascript

I have my form `formDrawer` below

```
<table id="drawer-table">
<form action="" method="post" name="formDrawer">
    <tr>
        <td>New Drawer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="20"/> </textarea>       
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Prefix</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="prefix" size="10" maxlength="6"/> </textarea>      
        </td>
    </tr>
 </form>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label>
            <input type="submit" name="drawerAdd" value="Save"/>
            <input type="submit" name="pCancel" value="Cancel" />
            </label>
          </form>
      </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

below i added a PHP that creates table with the data inputted in my form. in the end column of my table i added `edit` in which i want to set the value of my controls in the form when i click it. I have my code below but it doesn't work. In my `a href` I added javascript but no luck.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
      {
      echo "<tr onMouseover=this.bgColor='#EEEEEE' onMouseout=this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['drawerName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['drawerPrefix'] . "</td>";

      echo "<td class='add-edit'><button type='button' onclick='this.formDrawer.prefix.value = ".$row['drawerPrefix'].";'>Edit</button></td>";

      echo "</tr>";
      }
```

Comment: `it doesn't work`, what is not working, what do you expect, what's the current behavior?

Comment: it does not set my the value of my textbox

Comment: Start with valid HTML, you should not have a form in a form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having trouble with:

```
<a id='myLink' href='#' onClick='$('a#myLink').click(function(){
  document.getElementsByName('prefix')[0].value=".$row['drawerName']."; return false;
  });'>Edit</a>
```

Within an inline listener, you can reference the current element using *this*. You also seem to be adding a click listener from a click listener on the same element, which doesn't make sense.

Also, if you need a button, use a button, not a link. So you might want to do something like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.form.prefix.value = 'whatever';">Set the value</button>
```

Comment: i have edited my question and replaced my link to button, this seems practical, but still i have problem in setting the values of my textbox.